# How to hide TabLayout instead of Toolbar on Recyclerview OnScroll?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm using a Collapsing Toolbar Layout and I want to hide the TabLayout instead of the Toolbar. For example, when I scroll down my recyclerview I want the TabLayout to be hidden and the toolbar to stay in place at the top. I'm nesting the Coordinator Layout inside the drawer, like so, I'm using this following structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:openDrawer="end">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapse_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:titleEnabled="false">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabMode="fixed">
            </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fab"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
                android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_navigation"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_filter_list_white_24dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

            <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
                android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                app:itemBackground="@color/colorBottomNavigationBar"
                app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_main_nav_item_style"
                app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_main_nav_item_style"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_items" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/platforms_filter_drawer"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryD"
        android:layout_width="215dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:paddingTop="12dp"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/filter_text_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="FILTER"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/header" />

            <Button
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/header"
                android:id="@+id/btn_clear"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:text="CLEAR"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/md_red_600"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.5dp"
            android:background="@color/md_grey_700" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer_list"
            android:layout_width="215dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

How can I accomplish this? Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:openDrawer="end">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapse_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:titleEnabled="false">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabMode="fixed">
            </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_filter_list_white_24dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

        <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            app:itemBackground="@color/colorBottomNavigationBar"
            app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_main_nav_item_style"
            app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_main_nav_item_style"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_items" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/platforms_filter_drawer"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryD"
    android:layout_width="215dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:paddingTop="12dp"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/filter_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="FILTER"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/header" />

        <Button
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/header"
            android:id="@+id/btn_clear"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:text="CLEAR"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/md_red_600"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
        android:background="@color/md_grey_700" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer_list"
        android:layout_width="215dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```